# Return statement in while loop is inexplicably exiting the function prematurely

Tags: javascript

i am newbie in Javascript, but i try to create a code, which access to Sharepoint-list.
I have this code to access to the List "Mytasks", and i want to get the items in a select-tag. Now it show only the first item of the list. I can't find the issue.

```js
// load all necessary sharepoint javascript libaries
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {

 // load the sharepoint list.
 loadSharepointList();
});

// loads the sharepoint list
function loadSharepointList() {

 // create the sharepoint content.
 var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

 // get the list by the title.
 var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('myTasks');

 // create the query.
 var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();
 caml.set_viewXml("<Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='Title' /></IsNotNull></Where></Query>");

 // get the list items asynchronously
 var listItems = list.getItems(caml);
 context.load(listItems, 'Include(Title)');
 context.executeQueryAsync(

     // success delegate
     Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
     
      // loop through the items.
      var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();
      while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {

       // get the current list item.
       var listItem = listEnumerator.get_current();

       // get the field value.
       var fieldValue = listItem.get_item('Title');
    
       var list = document.getElementById("tstList");
       var option = document.createElement("option");
       option.text = fieldValue;
       list.add(option);
      // console.log(fieldValue);
       return "<option>" + fieldValue + "</option>";
       
      }
      }),

     // error delegate
     Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
      alert('Error fetching data from Sharepoint!');
     }));

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: the line `return "<option>" + fieldValue + "</option>";` exits **the entire function**, ending the `while` loop prematurely.

Comment: We actually don't care about where you are in your personal JavaScript learning experience, and it's irrelevant to your question, and certainly does not need to be put in the title of your question. Anyway, to solve your issue, just step through your program with the debugger in devtools. If you don't know what that is, or how to do it, then drop everything else you are working on and learn now.

Comment: "is inexplicably exiting the function" - what did you think is the purpose of `return`?

Answer (score 0):

i solved my issue. i moved the line var list = document.getElementById("tstList"); before the while-loop and the return i moved after the loop. So now it's fine. Thanks for your answers.